# Weird behavior of InterpolationOrder option of Interpolation

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, mathematica-8, mathematica-7

When trying to recreate an `InterpolationFunction` produced by `NDSolve` I faced very strange problem with `InterpolationOrder` option of `Interpolation`. Consider the following `InterpolationFunction` (an example function [from the Documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/NDSolvePackages.html)):

```
ifun = First[
  x /. NDSolve[{x'[t] == Exp[x[t]] - x[t], x[0] == 1}, x, {t, 0, 10}]]
```

Now let us to try to reconstruct it. Here is the data:

```
Needs["DifferentialEquations`InterpolatingFunctionAnatomy`"]
data = Transpose@{InterpolatingFunctionGrid[ifun], 
   InterpolatingFunctionValuesOnGrid[ifun]};
```

And here is `InterpolationOrder`:

```
interpolationOrder = InterpolatingFunctionInterpolationOrder[ifun]
(*=> {3}*)
```

Now we try to construct the `InterpolatingFunction`:

```
Interpolation[data, InterpolationOrder -> interpolationOrder];
```

and get error `Message`:

> Interpolation::inord: Value of option InterpolationOrder -> {3} should
>   be a non-negative machine-sized integer or a list of integers with
>   length equal to the number of dimensions, 1. >>

But if we specify `InterpolationOrder` by hands, it is OK:

```
Interpolation[data, InterpolationOrder -> {3}]
(*=> InterpolatingFunction[{{0.,0.516019}},<>]*)
```

Can anyone explain why `InterpolationOrder -> interpolationOrder` does not work while `InterpolationOrder -> {3}` works although `interpolationOrder` must be replaced with `{3}` BEFORE calling `Interpolation` according to [the standard evaluation sequence](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/Evaluation.html)?

P.S. The problem occurs in *Mathematica* 7.0.1 and 8.0.1 but not in *Mathematica* 5.2.

### UPDATE

I have found one workaround for this bug:

```
Interpolation[data, 
 ToExpression@ToString[InterpolationOrder -> interpolationOrder]]
```

works as expected.

It seems that expressions generated by evaluation of `Rule[InterpolationOrder,interpolationOrder]` and `Rule[InterpolationOrder,{3}]` has different internal structure in spite of the fact that they are identical:

```
ByteCount // Attributes
ByteCount[InterpolationOrder -> interpolationOrder]
ByteCount[InterpolationOrder -> {3}]
Order[InterpolationOrder -> interpolationOrder, 
 InterpolationOrder -> {3}]

(*=> 
{Protected}
192
112    
0
*)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that I have found the reason for this behavior. It is because `InterpolatingFunctionInterpolationOrder` function returns `PackedArray`:

```
Developer`PackedArrayQ@InterpolatingFunctionInterpolationOrder[ifun]
(*=> True*)
```

We can convert `{3}` into `PackedArray` ourselves:

```
Interpolation[data, 
  InterpolationOrder -> Developer`ToPackedArray@{3}];

(*=> gives the error Message*)
```

So the reason is that `Interpolate` does not support `PackedArray` as a value for `InterpolationOrder` option. The workaround is to unpack it manually:

```
Interpolation[data, 
 InterpolationOrder -> Developer`FromPackedArray@interpolationOrder]
(*=> InterpolatingFunction[{{0.,0.516019}},<>]*)
```

Answer (score 2):

Very strange behaviour indeed. Something like

```
a = {3};
Interpolation[data, InterpolationOrder -> a]
```

works fine, and both `??interpolationOrder` and `OwnValues[interpolationOrder]` seem to indicate that `interpolationOrder` is just equal to `{3}`. Even weirder is that this does seem to work

```
interpolationOrder = 2 InterpolatingFunctionInterpolationOrder[ifun]/2
Interpolation[data, InterpolationOrder -> interpolationOrder]
```

Comment: Division by 2 results in unpacking because rational numbers cannot be packed. See my answer for further details.